# Angular mat-sidenav is not showing unless content height is set

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

Was trying to get material sidebar to open over two hours, and discovered, that if there is no height set on sidenav-content, then sidebar is not opening at all.
My goal is to have sidebar full height always on the left side, not same height what content has. Current situation with 40vh: [SideNav not full height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DkED.png)

Does somebody know why it is so, or should my sidenav-content be something different than at the moment?

```
    <app-header (toggleSidenav)="navigationSidenav.toggle()"></app-header>
    <mat-sidenav-container autosize="true">
      <mat-sidenav #navigationSidenav [fixedInViewport]="false">
        <mat-nav-list>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/accounts'"> Accounts </a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/create-account'"> Create Account </a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/contacts'"> Contacts </a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/create-contact'"> Create Contact </a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/activities'"> Activities </a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/create-activity'"> Create Activity </a>
          <a mat-list-item (click)="navigationSidenav.toggle()">Close</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div style="height: 40vh;">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

App header looks like so

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
 <mat-toolbar-row>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSidenav.emit()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Official docs:

> The `<mat-sidenav>` will, by default, fit the size of its content.

Therefore, you should tell the component **explicitly** what is the desired height.